# PHP: Recursively creating a two-dimensional array from an $x-deep multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, phpexcel

In order to create a report for Excel, I need to create a two-dimensional array:

```
[0] => Array (
    [0] = Value A1
    [1] = Value B1
    [2] = Value C1a
    [3] = Value C1b
)
[1] => Array (
    [0] = Value A1
    [1] = Value B1
    [2] = Value C2a
    [3] = Value C2b
)
[2] => Array (
    [0] = Value A1
    [1] = Value B1
    [2] = Value C3a
    [3] = Value C3b
)
[3] => Array (
    [0] = Value A1
    [1] = Value B2
    [2] = Value C4a
    [3] = Value C4b
)
[4] => Array (
    [0] = Value A1
    [1] = Value B2
    [2] = Value C5a
    [3] = Value C5b
) ...
```

From an $x-deep (1-5 levels) multidimensional array:

```
[0] => Array (
    [name] = Value A1
    [data] => Array (
        [0] => Array(
            [name] = Value B1
            [data] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [name] = Value C1a
                    [secondary] = Value C1b
                )
                [1] => Array (
                    [name] = Value C2a
                    [secondary] = Value C2b
                )
                [2] => Array (
                    [name] = Value C3a
                    [secondary] = Value C3b
                )
            )
        )
        [1] => Array(
            [name] = Value B2
            [data] => Array (
                [1] => Array (
                    [name] = Value C4a
                    [secondary] = Value C4b
                )
                [2] => Array (
                    [name] = Value C5a
                    [secondary] = Value C5b
                )
                [3] => Array (
                    [name] = Value C6a
                    [secondary] = Value C6b
                )
            )
        )
    )
[1] => Array (
    [name] = Value A2
    [data] => Array (
        [0] => Array(
            [name] = Value B1
            [data] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [name] = Value C1a
                    [secondary] = Value C1b
                )
                [1] => Array (
                    [name] = Value C2a
                    [secondary] = Value C2b
                )
                [2] => Array (
                    [name] = Value C3
                    [secondary] = Value C3b
                )
            )
        )
        [1] => Array(
            [name] = Value B2
            [data] => Array (
                [1] => Array (
                    [name] = Value C4a
                    [secondary] = Value C4b
                )
                [2] => Array (
                    [name] = Value C5a
                    [secondary] = Value C5b
                )
                [3] => Array (
                    [name] = Value C6a
                    [secondary] = Value C6b
                )
            )
        )
    )
) ...
```

Where a recursive call checks to see if `[data]` is populated before passing that array of data into itself.

After trying multiple methods of iterating over the array recursively (foreach(), RecursiveArrayIterator, array_walk() etc.), I can't seem to properly build the required array after reaching the end of "B1" and switching to "B2" - since multiple elements (1 or more) are added when iterating through "C", I'll end up with an array the looks more like this:

```
[3] => Array (
    [0] = Value A1
    [1] = Value B1
    [2] = Value B2
    [3] = Value C4a
    [4] = Value C4b
)
```

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Cheers!

**EDIT:**

Adding the code in its current half-developed-hair-pulling-state

```php
<?php
class Report {
    //
    // Data processors and other functions snipped
    //
    public function flattenForExcel() {
        $excelArray = [];
        $index      = 0;
        $data       = $this->getProcessedData();
        foreach ($data as $datum) {
            $excelArray = $this->recursivelyFlattenForExcel($datum, $excelArray, $index);
        }
        return $excelArray;
    }

    public function recursivelyFlattenForExcel($datum, $returnArray, &$index) {
        $added       = 0;
        $showInExcel = $datum['config']['show_in_excel'];
        foreach ($showInExcel as $showValue) {
            $returnArray[$index][] = $datum[$showValue];
            $added++;
        }

        $cloneArray = array_slice($returnArray[$index], 0, $added * -1);

        if (!empty($datum['data'])) {
            foreach ($datum['data'] as $moreDatum) {
                $returnArray = $this->recursivelyFlattenForExcel($moreDatum, $returnArray, $index);
            }
        } else {
            $index++;
        }
        $returnArray[$index] = $cloneArray;

        return $returnArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, please post the code you have tried with to see what you mean when you say you can't build the array after reaching the end of B1.

Comment: Hi Solarc, I've updated the question with the code currently being used, although to be fair I was hoping to understand a better approach to a problem like this rather than trying to fix code that I've been getting more and more annoyed at! Ta.